# i2c in Ubuntu mate for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

To activate i2c block I followed the steps from this link
[rPi3 and I2c,SPI](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/rpi3-and-i2c-spi/4541)

but still I'm getting these errors.

```
Error: Could not open file `/dev/i2c-1' or `/dev/i2c/1': No such file or directory
```

I have also followed my steps from different forums. But I'm not able to find the solution for this error.

Thank you